# How do I use map() to assign array elements to different variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

to clarify I'm using React, Node, Postgres, Express.

I have an express route that return a table row, where each element is a different column. I want to assign each of these elements to a variable, here is an example of how the return results will look like:

```
Object { test1_id: "4", parts_id: 26, parts_material: "Plexiglass", … }
​
parts_id: 26
​
parts_material: "Plexiglass"
​​
parts_material_length: "49.78"
​​
parts_material_thickness: "1.86"
​​
parts_material_width: "24.96"
​​
parts_produced: 5
​​
test1_id: "4"
​​
workorder_id: 2
​​
workorder_total: 76
```

And here is my attempt at mapping these elements to seperate variables:

```
let thickness1 = 0;
    let width1 = 0;
    let length1 = 0;
    let partNeeded = 0;

// Material requirements calculation
    const getReq = async (id) => {
        try {
            console.log(materials);

            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/materials/${id}`, [id])
            const jsonData = await response.json();

            jsonData.map(x => x.parts_material_thickness = thickness1);

            console.log(jsonData)
            console.log('ID is: ',id)
            //console.log();
            //console.log('Thickness is: ', thickness1);


        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
```

My goal here is that every row will have different results, and the variables `thickness1`, etc will have different values depending on the array that was returned. In the example I provided I only tried mapping 1 variable, but even that isn't working. So how would I go using map() to map my array elements to different variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiply specific object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528182/multiply-specific-object-in-array)

Comment: No. `map` is not going to help you here, that works only on arrays.

Comment: "*I have an express route that return a table row*", "*every row will have different results*" - do you have *one* row (an object) or *many* (an array of objects)? It's not clear. Please post the JSON that your API returns.

Comment: you can check my answer below @test3r123

Comment: @Bergi I included the JSON that will be returned. To clarify, I have a table with columns and I want to map the values for those column to individual variables. So for the sake of example if I get returned {1, 2, 3 , 4, 5}, I want to map it as:

x = 1

y = 2

z = 3

f = 4... etc.

Comment: @test3r123 Oh, that's not JSON, that's a console printout. But ok, if you say you have only a single object, then you definitely can't use `map()`. It sounds like what you want is to use destructuring syntax instead. What do you want to do with those variables? Notice that it is not possible to dynamically declare variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `.map()` for this task, but not on the `jsonData` array itself, but on the array of the properties of your row object.

```js
// This assumes that:
// 1. The order of values in jsonData matches
//    with the order of properties in the row object.
// 2. The row object already has properties (has columns)
//    but no values yet (undefined or null)
const assignedRowEntries = Object.entries(rowObject).map(
    [key, value], index => [key, jsonData[index]]
);

console.log(assignedRowEntries);
// assignedRowEntries should look like this:
// [
//    [parts_id, value1],
//    [parts_material, value2],
//    ...
//    [workorder_total, value3]
// ]

// This is what you needed
const assignedRowObject = Object.fromEntries(assignedRowEntries);
```

More about [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Comment: TBH I gave up trying to get it to work with map(), using useState() instead works just fine. I'll have to figure out how to get it work with map() one day, thanks!